# Java pass by value and recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, arraylist

I have simple code which prints path to a specific node in a tree. My implemention using java String is as below

```
//using strings
public static void getPathS(Node node,String path,int key){
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    } else if(node.data == key) {
        System.out.println(path+" "+key);;
    }

    getPathS(node.left,path+" "+node.data,key);
    getPathS(node.right,path+" "+node.data,key);
}
```

Suppose there is tree as give below,

[image]

if I call getPathS on 3 , Above implementation will print

```
1 34 3 //path from root to the element
```

If I implement same method using ArrayList as below

```
public static List getPath(Node node, List<Integer> path, int key) { 
    if (node == null) {
        //1 . path = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        path = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        // 2. or tried path.clear()  -- it should clear the path
        //return path;
        return null;
    } else if (node.data == key) {
        path.add(node.data);
        return path;
    }

    path.add(node.data);
    return nonNull(getPath(node.left, path, key), getPath(node.right, path, key));
}

private List nonNull(List path1, List path2) {
    if (path1 != null)
        return path1;
    if(path2 !=null )
        return path2;
    return null;
}

// class Node { Node left, Node right , int data; };
//Code to call getPath  
Node node = new Node(1);
node.left = new Node(2);
node.left.left = new Node(4);
node.right = new Node(34);
node.right.right = new Node(3);
System.out.println(getPath(node, new ArrayList(), 3));
```

In second implementation, I tried two approaches, when we get NULL node,  in 1st approach if I assign new `ArrayList` to path, it prints all the elements i.e.

```
[1, 2, 4, 34, 3]
```

If I use `path.clear()`, it only prints last element i.e. element to be searched.

How can we make sure `ArrayList` will work as String in recursion ?

Comment: What is `nonNull(arg1,arg2)` ?

Comment: Ok thanks. Please post the code that calls `getPath()` the first time. The problem here is that you're adding/removing elements to the same list I guess. You need to use some sort of backtracking. I'll come up with something in a few minutes.

Comment: FYI, your new `nonNull()` method does the exact same thing ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't consider failure for both branches with your call to `nonNull()`.
Here is a correction that takes into account that possibility, and removes the data of the current node if we failed to find the key in its children.

```
public static List<Integer> getPath(Node node, List<Integer> path, int key) {
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (node.data == key) {
        path.add(node.data);
        return path;
    }
    path.add(node.data);

    // path is unchanged if nothing is found in left children
    if (getPath(node.left, path, key) != null || getPath(node.right, path, key) != null) {
        // found in one branch or the other
        return path;
    }

    // not found in either branch, remove our data
    path.remove(path.size() - 1);
    return null;
}
```

Of course, it looks like we're manipulating different lists, but there is only one: the one provided as argument the first time. That's why data should be removed from it. You need to be clear about your arguments.

---

A cleaner solution, that emphasizes the fact that there is one list only.

```
/**
 * Appends to the specified list all keys from {@code node} to the {@link Node} containing the
 * specified {@code key}. If the key is not found in the specified node's children, the list is
 * guaranteed to be unchanged. If the key is found among the children, then the specified list
 * will contain the new elements (in addition to the old ones).
 * 
 * @param node
 *            the node to start at
 * @param path
 *            the current path to append data to
 * @param key
 *            the key to stop at
 * @return true if the key was found among the specified node's children, false otherwise
 */
public static boolean getPath(Node node, List<Integer> path, int key) {
    if (node == null) {
        // leaf reached, and the key was not found
        return false;
    }

    // add data to the path
    path.add(node.data);

    // the OR is lazy here, so we treat everything in the given order
    // if getPath failed on the left children, path is unchanged and used for right children
    if (node.data == key || getPath(node.left, path, key) || getPath(node.right, path, key)) {
        // the key is found in the current node, its left children, or its right children
        return true;
    }

    // not found in either branch, remove our data
    path.remove(path.size() - 1);
    return false;
}
```

Note that I didn't use `path.remove(node.data)` because there could be more that one node with that data, and the first one would be removed instead of the last.

Comment: actually I came up with a better solution (cleaner), I'll post it in a minute